# Am I using the correct order for this kind of segmentation?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to make an automatic adaptive segmentation for this kind of images:

[image: Example image]

All of them are bees' wings but the size of the image, the species of the bee, the camera, almost everything might be a little different.

I'm currently using OpenCV getting good results, doing the segmentation in this order:

- Gray image
- Smootheness(Median and BilateralFilter)
- Treasholding(Adaptive Mean)
- Remove small objects
- Dilation
- Remove median objects
- Dilation
- Remove big objects
- Erosion

These dilations are used to connect the edges.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve, using manual segmentation:

[image: Manual segmentation]

Any suggestion that I can try to make it better? I prefer in OpenCV (Python).

Comment: Please provide your code, and the current output(s) you get. (The provided image says manual segmentation.) Do you actually encounter problems/errors, maybe for other inputs as shown here? Then, please also provide these. Right now, it seems, you have a working algorithm, and it's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You might look into [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/03/04/holistically-nested-edge-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) and opencv [watershed algorithm](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html)

Comment: Please, can you guys help me with my last question? It's much more clear now.